# Gradle include build

Tags: gradle, jar, build

How include some files (folders) from **build** directory, after project compile?

I have project with such structure

```
root
--moduleA
--moduleB
```

So I want after build all project
moduleA.jar include **build** directory from moduleA and **build** directory from moduleB

I found small example https://gist.github.com/marcokrikke/5481001
But it don't work on multi-project builds

**Add info**
github.com/feedm3/spring-boot-gwt 
After compile all GWT filesd exists in

```
ext.buildDir = "${project.buildDir}/gwt"
ext.extraDir = "${project.buildDir}/extra"
```

And they must be in jar

This example work fine. But I have problem with multi-project builds

Comment: Unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve. The build directory contains plenty of stuff, and you most probably don't care about most of what is there: test results, coverage reports, javadoc, temporary files, etc. What does "include some files" mean? What do you want to produce, where, containing what?

Comment: https://github.com/feedm3/spring-boot-gwt After compile all GWT filesd exists in ext.buildDir = "${project.buildDir}/gwt" and ext.extraDir = "${project.buildDir}/extra" And they must be in jar

Comment: May be change path ext.buildDir = "${project.buildDir}/gwt"  to resource?

Comment: Still unclear. 1: which jar? 2. The link you gave to github.com/feedm3/spring-boot-gwt shows that building the project already puts everything into a single jar.

Comment: Yes. But I have first submodule spring-boot and the second gwt-client. So when gwt-client build all generated gwt files must be copy into resource/static spring-boot submodule

Comment: Ah. So, modulaA is backend. moduleB is frontend. And you want the files generated by the frontend build to be included in the spring-boot jar file generated in the backend. So you need something like this: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/globe42/blob/master/backend/build.gradle#L41. The path inside the jar could be different, based o your versionof spring-boot. Read your spring-boot gradle plugin documentation.

Comment: Thank all work!!!